# Do I use all grounding screws in a metal box?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I'm wiring a 4-gang, metal box to hold multiple switches. It has 4 grounding screws. Do I need to pigtail around each of the box's grounding screws? My plan is to splice all the grounds together with additional grounds to go to each switch and have one of the grounds pig-tailed around a single grounding screw. Would this be allowed by the NEC or do I need to pigtail around each of the box's grounding screws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just one screw to the box, but you might find it easier to connect all the grounds from one half to one screw and the other half to another.

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing the dividers between the box as one unit then use one grounding location on the box.Run one ground from each switch and pig tail the 4 grounds from the switches,the ground screw wire,and the grounds from the branch circuits coming it.Use a crimp ring.Also if your screws have a grounding strap on them,u will know by one mounting screw will have a clip the screw passes through.If so then remove the plastic screw keepers on the switches,ground the box in one location.You will not need to individually need to run ground wires to each switch.Just bond box.IF ITS A Metal Box.

Comment: I know *nix likes their syntax terse. However, if you would please [edit] your post to fully spell out words, put spaces between sentences, etc., that would make your answer much more readable. Heck, you could even throw in a couple of `<Enter>`s to format it into some paragraphs to separate your thoughts.